# PDF Viewer on Chrome adds space in bottom when re-sizing/moving browser window

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, browser, pdf-viewer

We have an application which generates PDF reports. When we generate a report, it opens and displays on a new tab. Now if we click on the Restore Down/Maximize button on the browser window twice or move the window to another screen and back to the original screen, Chrome adds a white space at the bottom (does not affect the PDF or its contents). How do we get rid of this?

This does not happen if we save the file and open in Chrome browser. Only happens when it directly renders from a link (without .pdf at the end in the url) as shown in screenshots.

Before re-sizing:

[image: Before re-sizing]

After re-sizing: (Note: bottom black line is for reference)

[image: After re-sizing]

Comment: Based on the positioning of the buttons, it appears that it's the size of the PDF window changing, not anything within the PDF viewer. Are you sure that nothing else is changing the webpage when you minimize and restore?

Comment: Nothing else is changing the webpage. Just a click on Restore and then Maximize does this. It is hard to make out whether this extra space is in the Viewer or the browser window itself. The scroll bar on the right, ends before the white space at the bottom. But the white space is part of the window itself so I am not sure if it is the browser window or the viewer built-in Chrome which creates that extra space.

Comment: Try zooming in to the document and see where it ends.